# Container in provider construct. Symfony 2.4.*

Tags: php, symfony, oauth

`services.yml`:

```
parameters:
    uasector.user.abstract_social_network_provider.class: Uasector\UserBundle\UserProvider\AbstractSocialNetworkProvider

services:
    uasector_user.uasector_abstract_user_data_service:
        class: %uasector.user.abstract_social_network_provider.class%
        arguments: ['@service_container', '%kernel.root_dir%', '%uasector_user.image.upload_directory%', '%uasector_user.image.default_avatar_path%']
```

`AbstractSocialNetworkProvider.php`:

```
public function __construct(Container $container, $kernelWebDir, $uploadDir, $defaultAvatarPath) //Container $container, $kernelWebDir, $uploadDir, $defaultAvatarPath
{

}
```

**Error:**

```
ContextErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Uasector\UserBundle\UserProvider\AbstractSocialNetworkProvider::__construct() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container, none given, called in /Users/roman/Development/Sites/uasector.dev/app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php on line 6117 and defined in /Users/roman/Development/Sites/uasector.dev/src/Uasector/UserBundle/UserProvider/AbstractSocialNetworkProvider.php line 35
```

Why `AbstractSocialNetworkProvider::__construct()` does not accept `Container $container`?

[Repo!](https://github.com/RomanGorbatko/sy2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The container isn't built when you construct your class. To inject the container you should use a setter like..

Your class.

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

class AcmeClass
{
    ...

    protected $container;

    public function __construct(...)
    {
        ...
    }

    public function setContainer(ContainerInterface $container = null)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }
}
```

Your services.

```
parameters:
    uasector.user.abstract_social_network_provider.class:
            Uasector\UserBundle\UserProvider\AbstractSocialNetworkProvider
            // Split to 2 lines for readability

services:
    uasector_user.uasector_abstract_user_data_service:
        class: %uasector.user.abstract_social_network_provider.class%
        arguments:
            - '%kernel.root_dir%'
            - '%uasector_user.image.upload_directory%'
            - '%uasector_user.image.default_avatar_path%'
        // These are called after construction before before you actually use it
        calls:
            - [ setContainer, [ @service_container ]]
```

**NOTE**

That being said it is generally better (if at all possible) to inject the specific services that you need into your service so as to avoid being tightly coupled to the service container, and it also make things a lot more visible from a glance (ie, when you look at a service definition/__construct you can see what is being injected rather than having to work through the whole class to find out what you are calling with `$this->container->get()`).